# Gmail filter when email address is not in To field

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters

We recently went from Outlook to G Suite at work. How can I recreate a filter like in Outlook when my email address is NOT in the To field on incoming mail to go to a label? Our team CCs us on multiple emails throughout the day and I don't want to miss/filter mail that is sent directly To my email address.